# Which method is called when application was minimized and is brought to the front again?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

I want a button to be always selected. In interface builder I selected the flag **highlighted**. When the button is touched a method is called on **Touch Up Inside**.

```
-(IBAction)openPage:(id)sender{
     button.highlighted = YES;
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
             openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.page.net"]];
}
```

So the browser is opened. When I return to my application the button is not selected anymore. Why isn't it selected?

What method is called when an application was minimized and when I return back to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can track this a couple ways. The first is to implement `-applicationDidBecomeActive:` in your app delegate. This method will be invoked any time your application transitions from an inactive state to active, including wake from sleep, returning from a phone call, on close of a just-received SMS notification, etc. Depending on what you want, this may be OK. It also has the advantage of being available on iOS 3.0+.

The alternative is to implement `-applicationWillEnterForeground:` in your app delegate. Though this method is only available on iOS 4.0+, it has the advantage that it's only invoked when the application is brought to the foreground after switching from another app.

If implementing this in the app delegate is unfeasible or otherwise undesirable, you can add notification observers for `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` and `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`.